# Why am I getting an async error when running my code in Visual Studio

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, python-asyncio

When I try to run my code in the Visual Studio code editor, I get this error:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/user/Desktop/ProjectName/Main/bot.py".   
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProjectName/Main/bot.py", line 8   
    async def on_message(message):  
        ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea why this could be happening, for some context I am on macOS and I have installed async through terminal with 'pip install async' however this did not work. I am also pretty sure that there code is fine as another person can run this exact code fine with no errors in VS. The code also runs fine when I run the .py with the Python 3.9 launcher.

Edit: this happens when the code is run in the terminal with python -u instead of python3 -u

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: What is the interpreter you have selected in VSCode?

Comment: GalaxyCat105 I am using Python 3.9

Comment: C.Nivs I'm not sure how I can check this

Comment: default on macos is python 2, the system installed python

Comment: The command `python` normally refers to Python 2.7. `python3` is for Python 3.

Comment: ForceBru Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for, any ideas on why the VS Code terminal uses python instead of python3 when it runs the code or how to change it?

Comment: @iTechyn -In VSCode, the terminal uses the python selected when you open the terminal (selected in the lower left corner of VS code). When it is not selected, it uses the first python of the python environment variable by default.